# Get range in cell values of xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i fix this?

```
def validate_forms():
        msg_haserror=""
        for val in range(35,43):
            if "NOK" in str(ws['C'+val].value):
                msg_haserror="true"

        print("-->",msg_haserror)
```

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

How can i concatenate in order to check for these specific values?

Comment: Trying changing your `if` statement to `if "NOK" in ws['C'+str(val)].value:`

Comment: it work, thank you. i get stuck with these little things